# Hashing Once Per Partition in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an `RDD[Things]`, where `Things` is a case class containing several fields (but no custom methods.) I need to run an expensive operation on `Things.foo_id`. Each `foo_id` appears thousands of times, so I don't want to run the hash on every row.

One obvious way is to do a group by, e.g.

```
val stuff: RDD[Things]
stuff.groupBy(_.foo_id).flatMap(expensive_operation)
```

But grouping data across partitions is expensive too, and I don't really need to group by `foo_id` globally–just doing this once per partition would be plenty. Is there a good way to run this operation once per `foo_id` per partition?

Edit: I've tried `mapPartitions` using the following code:

```
val stuff: RDD[Things]
val grouped = stuff.mapPartitions(it => it.toList.groupBy(_.foo_id))
grouped.flatMap(expensive_operation)
```

But this runs into out of memory errors even on relatively small datasets, probably because the list is loaded into memory. I couldn't find a way to group an iterator without loading the whole thing into memory.

Comment: Have you already tried `mapPartitions`?

Comment: Also, maybe you could do `stuff.map(t: Things => (t.foo_id, t))` and use a PairRDD function/partitioner

Comment: @DanieldePaula Thanks for the suggestions. I tried mapPartitions, but ran into memory errors–see the edit. I've looked into PairRDDs but haven't managed to figure out how I might use that here.

Comment: Can you share more details of the type of operation you need to apply for each grouped set? It's not clear for me which reason would make you need to group the data, but only once per partition.

Comment: @DanieldePaula There might be a way that doesn't involve grouping. I want to hash the `thing.foo_id`. Each `foo_id` appears thousands of times, and the hashing is expensive, so I don't want to hash each one individually,  hence the `groupBy`.

Comment: So maybe you can use `rdd.map(t => t.foo_id).distinct.map(hash(_))`